# Indexing images in google search for all users to find website while avoiding image theft

Tags: google, google-adsense, images, google-image-search, international

Currently my website is setup so that bots who attempt to access an image will get a hotlink message instead as an image. The problem with this setup is that my revenue on average has significantly dropped from about $1-$2 a day to about 1 to 10 cents a day. I believe its because visitors with no understanding of the english language visit my site through the images that were indexed in google image search, thereby generating valid adsense impressions.

So at this point, I feel my only options are:

1. Allow bots to access and index the images and pray I don't have to sue x number of companies for unlawfully using the images (Example: selling them and/or modifying them by a tiny amount and claiming it as theirs), and this option is what I don't want to take.
2. Do nothing and suffer with low income, which is what I also hate.
3. Hire x number of highly trustworthy people to help convert the text on the site to multiple different languages, which might cost me a fortune.

The only thing I'm thinking I can do is take a select few images off the site and have them indexed by google, but google wants to index only high quality images that can load fast, yet lower quality images load faster, but even if I did that, it might not be enough images indexed for people to notice the site.

What else can I do to rectify this issue?

Comment: how about delivering watermarked images instead of hotlinking message images? thus keeping your revenue stream through high visibility on google image search... that way you could avoid legal battles for all the hotlinked images, since they would in turn also bring in more traffic ...

Comment: Unfortunately, the site has over 500,000 images, and manually watermarking each one would take a lot of time. Thanks for the idea tho.

Comment: actually I would never manually watermark images. just like you deliver "hotlink-message"-images, you could pass the desired image through a watermarking function server-side. for example with php: https://github.com/andreCatita/imageWatermark

Comment: Wait. If by watermark, you mean slapping a company logo on in the corner instead of changing the whole image to something different, then that's already in effect, but the problem is people could still take it off and try to sell it, and wouldn't that count as cloaking to google because then the image in search results would differ from that on the website?

Comment: hmm, not really. this is how i would approach the problem: 1. image with no watermark is shown on the website. 2. if image is hotlinked from a non-whitelisted domain a watermark is slapped on it. thus you could whitelist google as well. 3. unfortunately this is doesn't prevent people from downloading your non-watermarked image from your website and using that elsewhere. but on the other hand, a lock on your door doesn't keep a motivated thief out of your house either ...

Comment: It really depends what these images are and what they are used for if _watermarking_ would be suitable, but a visual "watermark" would be some kind of pattern/logo that affects the entire image, whilst still being "viewable" - it's not something that can be trivially cropped from the image. You would allow Google/bots to index a low quality(?) (perhaps non watermarked if only low quality) image and have the higher quality (watermarked) image on your website.

Comment: Watermarking is different than placing a "bug" in the corner. The term "bug" comes from the television industry where a logo or bug is placed in the right hand lower corner to identify the network you are watching. A water mark does not even have to be visible. Mostly watermarks are only slightly visible and significant enough to cover the photo therefore cannot be cropped. The best watermarks are ones that cannot be seen. These are encoded into image and any stolen image even after editing and being re-sized can be recognized by the watermark. Most people would not even know it is there.

Comment: Watermarks and digital signatures can be registered and services exist for identifying illegal use of an image through the signature. I use http://www.smalleranimals.com/thumb.htm which is super affordable and the best in the world for managing mass edits of images including scaling, watermarks, and digital signatures. This is all they do. I suggest playing in trial mode even if it is not a solution for you. It could be educational and handy from time to time. I used it to manage an online image directory of about 50 million images before- so I can say it is really really effective and fast.

Comment: I was thinking of "The best watermarks are ones that cannot be directly seen", so I guess its ok to offer an image of different quality to google's index than what's on the site? Because I know with actual webpages, that if you advertise something different to google than what the page really is, then the webmaster guidelines is violated.

Comment: you can automate your image processing uploads so they add meta tag with the correct copyright information first, if it's online people will re-use it but you can file free DMCA requests for removals, frequent removals normally violate terms of hosting companies - who can act directly on them, you can also look into serving images as base 64 which is harder to copy